# Gradle multi-module. Check context of first module with EventListener from another module

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I have two modules, first runs Spring boot Application and second it is EventListener which loads files from resources when context starts. All this modules works well separately but I wanna to include event listener module to my first module (Spring boot module) to get all files from resource of my first module when it runs context.

My main module with setting.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    buildDir = file("${rootDir}/build")
    group = 'com.example'
    version =  "0.1.1"
}
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'maven'
}
```

setting.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'test-application'

include 'bootApplication'
include 'eventListener'
project(":eventListener").projectDir = file("C:/examples/eventListener")
```

My bootApplication.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.1.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group 'com.example.bootApplication'
version =  "0.1.1"
sourceCompatibility = '11'
targetCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

bootJar {
    baseName("bootApplication")
}

jar {
    enabled = true
}

dependencies {
    compile project(":eventListnere")
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:+'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:+'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

And my eventListener:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.1.RELEASE'`enter code here`
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group 'com.example.eventlistener'
version '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = '11'
targetCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    ext {
        spring_boot_version = '2.2.1.RELEASE'
    }
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:$spring_boot_version"
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'

    testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:$spring_boot_version"


    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}


jar.enabled = true
```

When I run my bootApplication main class it creates a eventlistener-.jar file in root build directory. But eventlistener module doesn't check the resource folder, I guess it doesn't see a bootApplication context. Maybe it should be collect to one jar file? It looks like I missed something in gradle build files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will just prefix this by saying I don't know if the stuff below is the actual cause of your problems. But you should probably change a few things related to the jar configuration no matter what.

The Spring Boot Gradle plugin is used to create a fat jar out of the project. By default it disables the normal `jar` task.

You are re-enabling the normal jar task through `jar.enabled = true`, which is fine. But you also need to give it another name as one will otherwise override the other. For instance, for your `eventListener` project, you could do this:

```
// eventListener/build.gradle
bootJar {
    classifier = 'boot'
}
```

However, if the `eventListener` is not actually a stand-alone executable, there is no need to create a boot jar from it. So unless you are using the plugin for other things, I would remove it from the eventListener completely:

```
// eventListener/build.gradle
plugins {
    // id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.1.RELEASE'`enter code here` <-- Remove this
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}
```

You can still use the Spring Boot starters in the project, you just don't need the plugin for repackaging the jar.

The same thing applies to your `bootApplication` project: you are both trying to create a fat executable jar at the same time as a normal jar. One will override the other. In this case, you probably don't need the normal jar, so you should disable the `jar` task again:

```
// eventListener/build.gradle
// jar.enabled = true <-- Remove this
```

Lastly, replace `compile project(":eventListnere")` with `implementation project(":eventListener")` and `testCompile` with `testImplementation` to avoid some deprecation warnings. The `maven` plugin is deprecated as well in favor of `maven-publish`. You can probably also get rid of `mavenLocal()` unless you are integrating with local Maven projects that you build yourself with `mvn install`.

The `eventListener`, if packaged correctly as a normal jar inside the fat jar of the `bootApplication`, should be able to access resources in both its own `resource` folder as well as the one from `bootApplication` when you run the latter.